# Install package inside a Gitlab-runner docker container

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a Gitlab-ci configuration for a project, where I want to copy files with `.less` extension inside `src` to `dist`, maintaining their paths. For this I use:

```
find .  -name '*.less' -exec rsync -R {} ../dist ';'
```

I installed the gitlab-runner image with:

```
docker pull gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

And run it with:

```
  docker run -d --name gitlab_runner --restart always \
    -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

And registered with:

```
  docker run --rm -t -i -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner register
```

with **docker** as executor —maybe this is important—.

This is the structure of my project:

```
.
├── .gitignore
├── .gitlab-ci.yml
├── README.md
├── package.json
├── dist
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │   └── MyComponent
│   │       ├── Loader.less
│   │       └── Loader.tsx
│   └── index.tsx
└── tsconfig.json
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@me/components",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Components library",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -d && cd src && find .  -name '*.less' -exec rsync -R {} ../dist ';' && cd ..",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
  }
}
```

And this is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - install
  - build

install:
  stage: install
  script:
    - npm install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist
```

As you see, the gitlab runner will run `npm run build`, which has the following line:

```
"build": "tsc -d && cd src && find .  -name '*.less' -exec rsync -R {} ../dist ';' && cd ..",
```

The problem is that I get this output:

```
$ npm run build

> @me/components@0.0.0 build /builds/me/components
> tsc -d && cd src && find .  -name '*.less' -exec rsync -R {} ../dist ';' && cd ..

find: 'rsync': No such file or directory
find: 'rsync': No such file or directory
find: 'rsync': No such file or directory
find: 'rsync': No such file or directory
```

I suppose that this is because the linux version of the gitlab runner docker image has no `rsync`.

If I enter the docker container while running with `docker exec -it 9387492637 bash` I can try to run `cd src && find .  -name '*.less' -exec rsync -R {} ../dist ';' && cd ..`

```
root@239f8a797:/test#  cd src && find .  -name '*.less' -exec rsync -R {} ../dist ';' && cd ..
find: 'rsync': No such file or directory
find: 'rsync': No such file or directory
```

If I try to install `rsync` it fails:

```
root@239f8a797:/test# apt-get install rsync
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rsync
```

Is it because `rsync` is not installed in gitlab-runner image? Is because the executor? How can I fix this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks like the `node:latest` image does not have `rsync`. You can install `rsync` before the script runs:

```
before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq rsync
```

Or your `.gitlab-ci.yml` in full:

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - install
  - build

install:
  stage: install
  script:
    - npm install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/

build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq rsync
  script:
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist
```

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest to add `rsync` in extended image and use that image instead of offical image if does not contain `rsync` otherwise you will need `docker exec` everytime.

```
FROM gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
RUN apt-get update -y && \
apt-get install rsync -y
```

Or another option is

```
docker exec -it 9387492637 bash -c "apt-get update -y && apt-get install rsync -y"
```

**Updated:**
From @zeehio answer I also assume it something wrong with nodejs. So you can follow method of @zeehio or you can use this approach too.

```
FROM node:latest
RUN apt-get update -y && \
apt-get install rsync -y
```

or I will suggest using `alpine based nodejs` image which is much lighter then `node:latest`

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache rsync
```

**Bonus:**

You got nodejs, npm and rsync in just **`80MB`**.

**node:latest**

`node:latest` is **907MB** which approx 9 times bigger then alpine.

Comment: Thanks @adiii! I used the answer by @zeehio, but I will try to implement this one too.